# How to resolve $Lightning is not defined error?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I'm trying to include a Lightning component in VisualForce page. I'm experiencing two issues. Here's my code.

```
CreditCard.app:

<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:CreditCardForm"/>
</aura:application>
```

**ISSUE 1:**
If I include `extends="ltng:outApp"`, I'm getting an error saying "Something has gone wrong. $Lightning is not defined". I'm able to preview the app if I remove that piece of code. What exactly is the reason for this?

**ISSUE 2:**
I'm trying to access the `CreditCardForm` component in Visualforce page. The code is below:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning"/>
    <script>

    $Lightning.use("c:CreditCard", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:CreditCardForm",
                                   {},
                                   "lightning",
                                   function(cmp) {
                                       // do some stuff
                                   });
    });


    </script>
</apex:page>
```

To include Lightning component in VF page, `extends="ltng:outApp"` needs to be included according to documentation. However, even after including that, the page is empty. Please suggest a solution. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue 1 ,You will not be able to preview .You will have to use Visualforce page to preview your component .

If you want to preview your component ,use another app where you can insert the aura component .

The second seems to be issue with your component not rendering anything .You can [download lightning inspector](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_intro.htm) and debug the issues .